# how to stop the reload the page manually in node and ejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am using the node as a server and front end in ejs. I am working with socket.io thats why i need to stop the manually refersh the page. User can't reload the page.If user press the reload current page button then in my case socket connect disconnected.

So I don't want to disconnect that. Is there any way to stop reloading the page manually

Comment: There is no real way of preventing that. It would also be bad for user experience. Never try to cripple the default browser functionality! Why don't you just reconnect the websocket after reload?

Comment: You can't prevent it. All you can do is warn user using page unload events. Why can't you reconnect socket anyway?

Comment: because on disconnecting i hit the service that service automatically logout the user. if reconnect the socket then in that case i have to do all the login procedure again

Comment: Or just delay the logout for x seconds to allow reconnecting.

Comment: if i set the delay to logout then my another funtionality is suffer which is when i close the browser i need to hit the logout webservice.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep kind of cookie or localstorage, 
so you will be able to identify user after reload.

You can pass parameters to server in connection with this snippet:

```
var socket = io.connect('/image/change', {query:"name=my_img_name"});
```

And in server side you will be able to get parameters with this code:

```
`console.log(socket.handshake.query.name);`
```